# Tools for testing web application

Tags: testing, web-applications

I am looking for tool which I could use for:

- check avalibility pages
- check avalibility of resources on the page(css, js, images)
- sitemap
- opensource
- linux

I know about JMeter, but it is too comprehensive for this problem. Please advice me any helpful tool.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Selenium. It is a testing framework that has many adapters for common wide browsers.

Answer (score 0):

**Badboy** http://www.badboy.com.au/
is a very simple tool.
Thats works fine
It permit create and exports navigation scripts
to perfom separately.